# Is it possible to force validation with the MembershipProvider.ValidateUser?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I might need to add some sort of backdoor where a sysadm can log on to the aspnet.mvc site using a customers account knowing only the customers username.

Is this possible, for example using the hashed password from aspnet membershipprovider or a superuser password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get backdoor access, you do not need to know the user's password. Just their username.

You can do this by just writing `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false)`.

Just make sure you restrict access to this function. For example, create a role called "Authentication Agent". In the controller action method that does the backdoor access, make sure you only allow it for users in the "Authentication Agent" role.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize("Authentication Agent")]
public virtual ActionResult SignInAs(SignInAsForm model)
{
    if (model != null)
    {
        MembershipUser member = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.UserName))
        {
            model.UserName = model.UserName.Trim();
            member = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
        }

        if (member == null)
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", string.Format(
                "Username '{0}' could not be found.", model.UserName));

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Session["WasSignedInAs"] = User.Identity.Name;
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
            TempData["FlashMessage"] = string.Format(
                "Impersonation was successful. You are signed in as {0}.",
                    model.UserName)
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ReturnUrl))
                return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
            return RedirectToAction(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looking forward to try this tomorrow.